# How do I keep the constraints of my UILabels and put them in StackViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview, stackview

Notice in the image below, the 3 rows of 8's.

[image: MockUp]

All three rows initially have been set to `width: 45px` `height 45px` and then the following lines of code applied to make them round:

```
self.wonLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.wonLabel.layer.cornerRadius = self.wonLabel.frame.width/2
```

However, I want to arrange these UILabels within StackViews (along with their appropriate label) to keep everything neat and tidy in a grid format.

When I try to place a row of 8's in a StackView, the StackView automatically squashes the width of each UILabel - notice the 1st row of 8's.

How do I keep the constraints of my UILabels and put them in StackViews?